# How std::cin works in cpp

Tags: c++, cin

I wondered how **`std::cin`** is implemented in c++. Is it possible someone write a pseudocode which works just like `std::cin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You cannot** do any input/output in C++ without using *some* library (or some target specific assembler code), since you need to make some call to an external output function (or to some [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), or, if you are coding an operating system kernel or some other freestanding program, do some IO machine code instruction).

If you are coding above some [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) (this is generally the case), you might make some direct system calls. On Linux, they are listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) (but in practice you'll use some system `libc.so` shared [library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Shared_libraries)). On Windows (which I don't know) the exact set of (kernel-level) system calls is harder to get, but you could use some system [DLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library)s related to the [WinAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API). You could read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to learn more about OSes.

Many -but not all- [C++ standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library) implementations are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), and often coded above some [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) and/or above target-specific system calls. So you could study the source code of your C++ standard library (often released with the compiler, e.g. in [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and the source code of your C standard library (e.g. [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/)).

So if you are using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) on Linux, study its source code.

BTW `cin >>` operations are a large set of overloaded `std::istream::operator >>` [member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) functions and [global](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) functions.

Comment: Standard Library implementations are not going to be the easiest code for a beginner to read, but here is a [starting point](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/iostream).